# Howto to show program window in specific desktop using python

Tags: python, window, gtk3, freedesktop.org

I am writing python app and need to run another program in specific (not the current one) desktop in openbox (I have 4 desktops). There is freedesktop _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP param, but I don't know how to change it under python and gi.repository (Wnck, Gdk?). Or maybe use Xlib? I can't find what is best method to do it...

Answer (score 2):

With PyGTK, you would create a [gio.AppInfo](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gioappinfo.html) instance representing the application you want to launch, then provide a [gtk.gdk.AppLaunchContext](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkapplaunchcontext.html) to its [launch()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gioappinfo.html#method-gioappinfo--launch) method.

When you create the launch context, you would call its [set_desktop()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkapplaunchcontext.html#method-gdkapplaunchcontext--set-desktop) method to specify the index of the desktop the launched application will run on.